# Jmeter - How to exclude Beanshell preprocess time in HTTP Sampler

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am new to Jmeter. I have a http sampler in Jmeter which has a Beanshell Preprocessor.

Question is how to exclude time taken by Beanshell Preprocessor in http sampler.

Answer (score 1):

By default time taken by Post processor is excluded so nothing to do.

Note that it's much better to use Groovy+JSR223 Elements + cache key instead of BeanShell.

One note about [TransactionController](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller), it used to include Post Processing in reported response time but this has been changed in latest versions:

[image]